# How to transform a shape in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, matrix, graphics, rotatetransform

I'm trying to first draw a shape (which i've done already) and then have it transformed as selected by a user for example, rotated to a certain angle, or scaled, showing this original shape and the newly transformed shape.

I've tried the following on trying to rotate:

```
Private Sub paint_box_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles paint_box.Paint
    Dim x As Integer = paint_box.Size.Width / 2
    Dim y As Integer = paint_box.Size.Height / 2

    Dim rect As New Rectangle(x, y, 80, 80)

    ' Create pen.
    Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
    ' Create pen.
    Dim redPen As New Pen(Color.Red, 3)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect)
End Sub
```

I was expecting to have that shape printed on `Form.Load` to rotate by the specified angle `30.0F`

Comment: How do I invalidate it?

Comment: The part in not getting is how would I get that rectangle object, and apply some transformations and draw it along with the original? Could you demonstrate in an answer?

Comment: Slightly more complex: [Drawing and scaling rectangle using a ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54710125/7444103).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm looking for something that rotates that shape, the original

Comment: I now know how to use `Graphics.DrawRectangle()` I want to know how to pass those arguments example the angle to that control's `Paint` Event?

Comment: You can assign the rotation angle value to a Field (or a class property, it depends on the method you use to draw the shapes). When the angle changes, you call `[Control].Invalidate()` and use the Field/Property value to rotate the shape. Update your question with the drawing of a rectangle and I'll show you how to rotate it.

Comment: @jimi Just edited. I'm drawing the shape in a groupBox control named paint_box

Comment: Edited the question with corrections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we want to paint on a Control's surface, we need subscribe to the [Paint event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint) of a Control (not all controls provide this event: TextBox controls don't, for example. We could derive a Custom Control class from TextBox and override the `OnPaint` method. It may be disappointing, though).

To paint and rotate a shape, we need some Fields or Properties to store the references of the objects/values we use for painting. Here, just the `Rectangle` object that provides the measure of the shape and a `single` Field to store the rotation angle.

```
Private drawingRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)
Private rotationAngle As Single = 0.0F
```

These references allow to change the shape of the object and the rotation angle when needed. When these values change, we just need to call the [Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate) method of a Control to raise its `Paint` event.

In `Form.Load()` (or in the Form's constructor - `Public Sub New()`) we can define the initial position and size of the shape, if required:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    drawingRect = New Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

When we change the measures of a shape, to update the drawing, we call the Control's **`Invalidate()`** method. Here, the drawing surface is provided by a GroupBox control.
On a `Button.Click()`, we update the shape with the new values calling **`GroupBox.Invalidate()`**. The drawing will be updated immediately:

```
Private Sub btnRotate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRotate.Click
    ' Rotate the shape 45 degrees
    rotationAngle = 45
    GroupBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

To rotate a shape, we can use two simple methods: the [Graphics.RotateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform) method, or the [Matrix.RotateAt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.rotateat) method.
I'm using the latter: it's very simple to use, it accepts an angle expressed in degrees and the we just need to provide the coordinates of the rotation.
Here, the shape is rotated using the coordinates of its center point:

```
Using mx As Matrix = New Matrix
    mx.RotateAt(rotationAngle, New PointF(drawingRect.X + (drawingRect.Width / 2.0F),
                                          drawingRect.Y + (drawingRect.Height / 2.0F)))
    e.Graphics.Transform = mx
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, drawingRect)
End Using
```

Sample of the results:

[image: Graphis DrawRectangle Matrix RotateAt]

See also:
[Drawing and scaling rectangle using a ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54710125/7444103)
[How to use the Paint event to draw shapes at mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708936/7444103)

All the code used to draw and rotate the shape:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private drawingRect As Rectangle = Rectangle.Empty
    Private rotationAngle As Single = 0.0F

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        drawingRect = New Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GroupBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Paint
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        Using pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.LightGreen, 4),
            mx As Matrix = New Matrix()

            mx.RotateAt(rotationAngle, New PointF(drawingRect.X + (drawingRect.Width / 2.0F),
                                                  drawingRect.Y + (drawingRect.Height / 2.0F)))
            e.Graphics.Transform = mx
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, drawingRect)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPaint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPaint.Click
        ' Redefine the shape and redraw it
        drawingRect.Location = New Point(100, 100)
        drawingRect.Size = New Size(200, 300)
        GroupBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRotate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRotate.Click
        ' Rotate the shape 45 degrees
        rotationAngle = 45
        GroupBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub
End Class
```