# Rotating BMP in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, bitmap

In short I have a little dial in the middle of the screen I want to use for the menu selection.. It needs to rotate 60 degrees between each option and its a bmp! I know how to rotate a bmp 90 degrees but is there anyway to rotate it just 60 in visual basic

Comment: See [Using a matrix to rotate rectangles individually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210639/719186)

Comment: Simple Bitmap rotation (center point): [Image.RotateFlip doesn't seem to rotate the Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764409/7444103) - Rotate and scale a shape (same for Bitmaps) [How to transform a shape in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075512/7444103) - More complex, accumulating all transformations: [Zoom and translate an Image from the mouse location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964222/7444103) (decentered Zoom, Panning, Scale, Rotate, Move)