# Drawing on bitmap with mouse is spaced out by the speed of the mouse

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, drawing

Im making a Drawing/Editing program. I have made a drawing tool, using this code on the `MouseMove` event:

```
If down = True Then
                Using br = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(ColorA, ColorR, ColorG, ColorB))
                    GFX.FillEllipse(br, e.X, e.Y, size, size)
                End Using
            End If
```

`GFX` is graphics from a bitmap called `IMG`.

`IMG` is projected on a `PictureBox`.

The color integers are for the color channels, `ColorA` is for the alpha channel.

The `down` boolean is to check if the mouse is down.

SolidBrush `br` is the brush used to render the color of the stroke

`e` is `MouseEventArgs`

Now that I explained the code I will head on the problem that im facing:

[image: My Problem]

I tried to draw a cricle with the drawing tool and I've noticed the "dots" were spaced out. It seems its more spaced out if the mouse is moving at a fast speed.

Do I need to get the raw input from the mouse? I really don't know, so how do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a line from the last position instead of an ellipse at the current position?

Comment: Good idea but how?

Comment: On the MouseDown event, store the mouse coordinates. On the MouseMove event, draw a line from the stored coordinates to the new mouse location, and store those new coordinates.

Comment: Free-hand using Bezier curves: [How to draw a signature and save it to disc as a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084653/7444103) -- Constrained by a specific shape or settings: [How to use the Paint event to draw shapes at mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708936/7444103), fixed ratio: [Drawing and scaling rectangle using a ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54710125/7444103)